# Excel Formula Using If/Then and Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a function such that excel will match the text from the Causes sheet, column A, to the text from column B on the Daily sheet. If there is text to match, then I want the information in the Causes sheet, column G from that row to paste to the selected cell.
This the formula I currently have:

```
=IF('Causes'!A3 ='Daily'!B3,'Causes'!G3,"")
```

I am just getting a blank return instead of a #VALUE! message or indication of what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `=INDEX('Causes'!G:G,MATCH('Daily'B3,'Causes'!A:A,0))`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need the corresponding matching text from Daily sheet into the causes sheet, you can use the formula "=VLOOKUP(A3,Daily!B:B,1,FALSE)" in column G of causes sheet.

Please find my explanation in the images attached.
[image: causes sheet]

[image: Daily sheet]